# Selecting a month from MM/DD/YYYY to insert,delete & update

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

I have a TextBox and a Button, and I have a DB which contains EmpID and Date. So I want to delete a EmpId depending on Date but not the exact date.

Let's suppose EmpId=2 and Date=02/20/2012 in DB. I should be able to Delete it even when i enter 02/25/2012 or 02/01/2012 so if the month and year matches it should be deleted. I enter the date in the TextBox.

```
con.Open();
try
{
    SqlCommand Delete = new SqlCommand("delete from Table2 where Date= ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')", con);
    Delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.writeLine("Error");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem apart from the fact you don't parse the date, so neither can the server?

Comment: what is the error or problem then and it is hard to understand what you are asking for

Comment: @NetStarter  i didnt get how to select mm from mm/dd/yyyy and delete upon the respective month

Comment: @t3hn00b i'm able to delete a record only if i enter a exact date but my requirement is to delete a record based on mm from mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: guys i'm still not able to get the output can any1 please help

Comment: what is your database server? what are the matching parts?

Comment: try something like this DateTime.tostring("MM");

Comment: @Kaf my DB is sql server 2008 Date column is in datetime fromat

Comment: @NetStarter i tried it but its not working. it gives a syntax error

Comment: @leppie thanks for editing and sorry was offline till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use the SQL MONTH and YEAR function.

E.g.

```
SqlCommand Delete = new SqlCommand("delete from Table2 where MONTH(Date) = MONTH('" + TextBox1.Text + "') AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR('" + TextBox1.Text + "'), con);
```

Comment: sorry i'm a fresher so could you please guide me how to  use month and year function in a sql query

Comment: Look up the functions in help or Google e.g. select * from TESTING where MONTH(Date) = MONTH('1/1/2013') and YEAR(Date) = YEAR('1/1/2013')

Comment: what type of query should i actually write??

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '01/01/2013'. is what i'm getting so should i convert it to date??

Comment: 'm blocked from asking questons can u please help me by giving a upvote to my question please

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change your front end from one text box to two controls.  The first one will be either a text box or a drop down and is used to submit the year.  The second would be a drop down to select the month.  This will give your users a clearer indication of what they are doing.  It also takes away the problem of invalid dates, such as 2013-02-30.

On the back end, if you have a year and a month, you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: thanks fro the idea surely i'll implement. this is a real nice and easy way to make the user understand so thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use below code in where clause

```
DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%m/%Y') = compare only month and year here in mm/yyyy format.
```

Hope this works foryou

Comment: Kumar Soneta is that the exact code which i have to implement??

Comment: what type of query should i actually write??

Comment: Sorry. was offline . still you looking for any kind of help in this ?

Comment: hey no i got the answer thanks for the help and i need another samll HELP from you..because of the downvotes i'm not able to post questions so if you could upvote the question it would really help me learn more as i'm a fresher... I request you to upvote my question and help me

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your textbox to datetime like below

```
DateTime dateValue =  DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

from variable dataValue you can get month and year . Now use below query

```
SqlCommand Delete = new SqlCommand("delete from Table2 where  datepart(mm,Date) = '" + dateValue.Month + "' And datepart(year,Date) = '" + dateValue.Year + "'", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTimePiker` control instead of `Textbox`, use this code:

```
SqlCommand Delete = new SqlCommand("delete from Table2 where Date= ('" + datetimepicker.value + "')", con);

Delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
```